# el layout '/~/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/_AuthLayout.cshtml' no puede ser encontrado

Tags: mvc, layout, asp.net-core-mvc

Quiero llamar desde las paginas web el nuevo layout `_AuthLayout.cshtml` pero parece que no reconoce la ruta del archivo.

Registro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Login:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ruta del archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el mensaje de error que me aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay ciertos lugares que recomiendan hacer esto, que cambie esto en las propiedades de `_AuthLayout.cshtml` de none a content, pero cuando intente ya estaba como content:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También intente darle click derecho a `_AuthLayout.cshtml` y darle a opción scope to this, pero no hace nada. Intenté solo poner en la ruta del `Layout = "_AuthLayout.cshtml";` y sigue con el problema.

¿Qué más puedo hacer para resolver este problema?

Answer (score 1):

Reemplaza:

```
Layout = "~/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/_AuthLayout.cshtml";
```

Por:

```
Layout = "~/Areas/Identity/Pages/_AuthLayout.cshtml";
```

Motivo:

El Layout que mencionas, está fuera del directorio `Account`

Comment: Hola y gracias por las correciones y la respuesta. Esta es la ruta completa donde esta el layout _AuthLayout: Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/. El layout en cuestion si esta dentro del directorio Account. Lamentablemente no puedo utilizar una imagen pero si esta. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: ¿De verdad? Porque según la imagen que tienes en la pregunta, para que esté en el directorio de Account, debería estar exactamente en la misma alineación que los demás archivos (_ViewImports, Login, Register).